# WordPress database error Unknown column

Tags: database, errors

I get this error in my database log:

> [05-May-2013 21:13:31 UTC] WordPress database error
>
> Unknown column 'region' in 'order clause' for query
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tmp1db_wpuf_customfields ORDER BY `region` DESC
> ```
>
> made by require('wp-blog-header.php'),
> require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
> include('/themes/ExtraGrid/single.php'),
> get_template_part,
> locate_template,
> load_template,
> require('/themes/ExtraGrid/content-single.php'),
> the_content,
> apply_filters('the_content'),
> call_user_func_array,
> wpuf_show_meta_front

What should I change?

Comment: k i figured out it is a error from *user frontend* plugin i still delete & reinstall.. lets see if this is solved

Answer (score 1):

There is a SQL query in the theme file `/themes/ExtraGrid/content-single.php`, and it is asking for a column that doesn’t exist.

This seems to be a commercial theme, so we can just guess why that query exists. Maybe you forgot to set a required theme option, or your tables are just incomplete.